# Weka supplied test set didn't process the full dataset

Tags: weka

When using Weka, i used the supply test set, the test dataset had around 3000 instances, why the processed data were only 107 instances?

I expected to have the fully supplied test set tested and processed, what could I have done wrong?

Comment: Post the textual output of the Weka Explorer with your question. Also, check the terminal and/or weka.log file for errors (in $USER/wekafiles or %USERPROFILE%\wekafiles).